# Error when pointing to the address

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a c program to create a simple linked list and when I tried equating the pointer of a struct variable to the address of the next the compiler throws an error. Can you please help me resolve it? Says the `int*` cannot be converted to `list`. Here's the code snippet:

```
struct list
{
    int n;
    struct list *p;
};

void main()
{
    struct list item0, item1;
    item0.n=1;
    item0.p=&item1.n;//The compiler is throwing an error here. Says they are two incompatible types
    item1.n=2;
    item1.p=NULL;
}
```

Comment: `item0.p=&item1;` is probably what you were going for.

Comment: Please try helping me out of this quickly.

Comment: Um. Did you **read** that comment ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be pointing to an address?

Comment: My print statement would include item0.n and *item0.p

Comment: The only error flagged was addressed in the first comment. I don't know what else you want. The first comment in this question is the code to correct the error you indicated you had problems with., and your last comment makes no sense at all (there is no "print" statement. Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry, for the laconic statement. Well when I tried the change you mentioned my output was 1-182. Not able to understand why?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be 1 2

Comment: Its your output, and no one here has any idea how you're doing it, since you chose not to post the code. Regardless, its a different problem than the compilation defect that you posted here. StackOverflow isn't an online interactive debugging service. If you have a different problem, post a different question please.

Comment: printf("\n%d", item0.n);
printf("\n%d", *item0.p);

Comment: Is `*item0.p` an `int` ? No, its a dereferenced pointer to a `list` node So why are you trying to print it as one.

Comment: Then can you please tell how I could print that? I found this code snippet in a book and I tried it out.

Comment: Then you mistyped. `printf("%d, %d\n", item0.n, item0.p->n);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. The book had made a mistake and I really didn't think that such a book could have a mistake. Thank you and sorry for your inconvenience due to my ineptitude.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler throws an error because `&item1.n` is read by the compiler as `(&item1).n` which is non sense. Because is C language, `&` operator has higher precedence than `.`.

As p is a `list *` you should write :

```
item0.p = &item1;
```

as n is first element of structure, you could also write (in C because it is not valid C++ without casting to `void *`) `item0.p = &(item1.n)` but it is *bad* because you assign a pointer to int to a pointer to list.

If you later want to print both, you print values of `item0.n`and `item0.p->n` because both are integers. As I wrote above you could write `int i = *((int *) item0.p)` but it is *ugly*. Writing things like that would soon lead to ununderstandable and unmaintainable code.

Comment: I changed as you suggested into item0.p=&item1 but when I print, printf("\n%d", item0.n);
printf("\n%d", *item0.p); The output is 1-182 instead of 1 2. Can you explain?

Comment: Thank you I spot the error and corrected with the help of WhozCrazy(^). Thanks for the help.